Safety of leaking memory
I recently learned that if you preform a Box::leak(Box::new(value)) and receive a &'static it becomes much easier to transfer values in between threads. I have one specific value which has to be accessible from different threads, however the problem is that I have to leak user login credentials, and as far as I'm aware if I do that, those credentials will not be cleared from the memory on application, exit. This makes me wonder if I shouldn't use this approach, or do modern operating systems have ways to stop malicious applications from collecting that data?


as far as I'm aware if I do that, those credentials will not be cleared from the memory on application, exit

The operating system will free all memory allocated by a process when that process terminates.  This includes all leaked memory.
Even if this were not the case, what you are describing is not a memory safety issue.  "Memory-safe" means something very specific, and it does not on its own include preventing access to sensitive information like passwords.  Memory safety means that the following things are not possible:

Out of bounds reads or writes.
Double-free.
Use-after-free.

The most succinct description of memory safety I can think of is "references to values always point at valid values" (though this may be a bit oversimplified).
To address why you're leaking memory in the first place: if all you're trying to do is share something between multiple threads, consider using Arc instead.  This implements a thread-safe reference counted smart pointer, which will free the held allocation when the last handle is dropped.  Unless you're doing something really weird or where the overhead of atomic operations causes performance problems, you can almost always use Arc instead of leaking.

As a side note, if you're concerned about the password persisting somewhere either on disk or after your program terminates, you want a "secure string."  Implementations of secure strings will typically do two very important things:

Lock the memory backing the string such that it cannot be swapped out to disk. This prevents leaking the password to the system's swap space (though this can still happen if the system is hibernated).
Zero the memory behind the string before freeing it.  This is significantly more complicated than just writing zero bytes over the string before it is deallocated.  Optimizers are very aggressive, and will do things like removing writes to memory that occur right before they are deallocated.  Optimizers are concerned with making your program faster/smaller by making changes that your program cannot observe.  Since your program can never actually observe that the memory was not zeroed, optimizers are within their rights to do this.  See the zeroize crate for an example of how this can be done correctly.


Thank you for the response, I'm aware of the Arc I was just recently looking at alternatives and stumbled on 'static. I might have phrased my question poorly, I'm aware that the system will free the memory however I believe that it will not zero the data, from which the questions about the safety as in security of the application arise. You just maid an edit that answered the question for the most part thanks lol.

@Laycookie the OS might not zero the memory instantly, but it will zero the memory if it's allocated to another process.

@drewtato I don't think this is true in general, mainstream modern OSs should do it, but it's not a guarantee.

@cafce25 I thought that the OS doesn't zero the data but malloc function specifically does.

malloc definitely doesn't zero the data (read: is not specified to zero the data). That's a thing calloc adds . The OS usually clears memory before it hands it to a process, but if when and how it does so depends on the OS and the specific syscall and thus is not guaranteed in general. I think Linux guarantees it for brk. But there are ways to request data from it that doesn't a mmap can be instructed not to clear the data with MAP_UNINITIALIZED for example (but it isn't always honored). @Laycookie

The OS will never let a process access non-zeroed memory of another process, because it can leak secrets of a privileged process. MAP_UNINITIALIZED AFAIK will only work for memory freed from the same process.
